# App Crashes when i add UIImageView to ASCellNode from AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, iphone, asyncdisplaykit

I am using Facebook's `AsyncDisplayKit` to create a `CollectionView` such that `CollectionView` is `ASCollectionView` and i am trying to add `UIKit's` `UIImageView` in the cell.I get following crash:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ''

  *** First throw call stack:
  (

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00bf2946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0087ba97 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bf27da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138

3   Foundation                          0x004ef810 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118

4   Sample                              0x000b21df -[ASDisplayNode view] + 607

5   Sample                              0x0007a0f5 -[PlainImageNode initWithCellOfSize:] + 533

6   Sample                              0x0007e34d -[ASVC_UIImage_ViewController collectionView:nodeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 269

7   Sample                              0x00085c36 -[ASCollectionView dataController:nodeAtIndexPath:] + 150


libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Following the code which crashes, this is the init method of the `ASCellNode` I created for my `ASCollectionView`. I am trying to add `UIImageView` into `ASCellNode`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCellOfSize:(CGSize)size
{
if (!(self = [super init]))
    return nil;

_kittenSize = size;

// kitten image, with a solid background colour serving as placeholder
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"];
_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
[self.view addSubview:_imageView];

[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
return self;
}
```

I am afraid if I can add `UIKit` components to `ASCollectionView's` `ASCellNode`. Is it true that we can't add `UIKit` components in `ASCellNode's` hierarchy?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with UIKit and AsyncDisplayKit. It must be your implementation, you need to see their sample more carefully. I guess you are trying to subclass `ASCellNode `, and doing some mistake there.

Comment: I have gone through the sample projects provided along with the library. However, i couldn't find an example where they were adding a UIKit component to the ASCellNode hierarchy. It would really help if you can point to some working code of adding any UIKit component to ASCellNode.

Comment: Similar issue with UIButton addition to ASCellNode : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831366/add-custom-button-with-asyncdisplaykit

Comment: Did you see this http://asyncdisplaykit.org/guide/ ? Don't use UIImageView, use `ASImageNode` instead. And if you want to create Custom Node here it is http://asyncdisplaykit.org/guide/2/

Comment: I have gone through the complete guide. I am trying to create a small POC to check if we can add UIKit components to ASCellNode because there are some UIKit components whose wrapper nodes are not available in ASDisplayKit. Hence as part of POC, I took UIImageView to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to add UIKit components in the ASCellNode subclass implementation using -[ASDisplayNode initWithViewBlock:].

Following is the code which wraps an ASDisplayNode over UIImageView and returns the resulting node :

```
ASDisplayNode *_imageViewNode = [[ASDisplayNode alloc] initWithViewBlock:^{
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"]];
    return image;
}];
_imageViewNode.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
[self addSubnode:_imageViewNode];
```

Similarly, code for UIWebView component :

```
ASDisplayNode *webViewNode = [[ASDisplayNode alloc]initWithViewBlock:^{

NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
[webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
return webview;
}];

[webViewNode setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:webViewNode.view];
```